# How to prevent hbm2ddl from importing init sqls?

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

Precondition:

1. There is an import.sql file in my classpath.
2. The property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" is set to "create".

Then, how to prevent hbm2ddl from import the init sqls, **without** delete the import file or modify the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property?

Answer (score 0):

Since Hibernate 3.6 you can override default name of the import file with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property. So, you can set a name of nonexistent file there.